# What is the Problem with this sql Update?

Tags: mysql

When I want to execute this sql update statement, I get a syntax error, but I don't see any syntax mistakes that I made.

```
UPDATE database1 
SET database1.Name = 'Hans', database1.Grund = 'Defekt', database1.Gerätename = 'Beamer', database1.Ausleihdatum = '15/3/2019', database1.Rückgabedatum = '29/3/2019', database1.Gerät_ID = database_geräte.ID 
FROM database1 
    INNER JOIN database_geräte ON database1.ID = database_geräte.ID 
WHERE database1.Name = 'Peter' AND database1.Grund = 'Altes Gerät defekt' AND database1.Gerätename = 'Beamer' AND database1.Ausleihdatum = '21/3/2019' AND database1.Rückgabedatum = '10/4/2019'
```

The update statement should work, but I don't know why...

Comment: Have you read the documentation? You don't need `FROM`, and `SET should be after `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar It appears the OP based his answer off SQL Server documentation.  Side note: the update name is `Beamer`, which sounds a lot like `Barmar` :-)

Comment: @Barmar I used the sysntax of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/how-do-i-update-from-a-select-in-sql-server)

Comment: @despamigros That's a sql-server question, not MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar it's not. I use this mysql querry in an access database...

Comment: Read the first line of that question, it says "In SQL Server". It also has the `sql-server` and `tsql` tags.

Comment: Since Access and SQL-Server are both from Microsoft, they may be similar.

Comment: @Barmas Sorry didn't saw that. Was just overreading the sql statement

Comment: Both don't work, so I think I simulate it in a mysql workbench or a sql server...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using SQL Server syntax for a MySQL update query.  In MySQL, the join comes first, followed afterward by `SET`:

```
UPDATE database1 t1
INNER JOIN database_geräte t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
SET
    t1.Name = 'Hans',
    t1.Grund = 'Defekt',
    t1.Gerätename = 'Beamer',
    t1.Ausleihdatum = '15/3/2019',
    t1.Rückgabedatum = '29/3/2019',
    t1.Gerät_ID = t2.ID;
```

Comment: @despamigros You have mentioned MySQL, SQL Server, and Access.  What is your actual database?  The above query should be running on MySQL without error, that is, unless you're not really running it on MySQL.

Comment: It is a access database, but the syntax is the same as in mysql

Comment: "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'database_geräte.ID FROM database1'.